# Sql server login name not working properly in .net roles

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, iis

I created one new sql login for configuring the forms based authentication in sharepoint. I created login with name **FBAUser**, but If I add that user to .net roles of IIS manager, it is showing login failed.
[image]
[image]

Why this problem occurring. After creating the new login in sql server, if I try to login with that credentials login also not happening. I checked the properties of the server as **"Sql and windows authentication mode"** as below.
[image]

Can any one provide me the solution for this one!!

Comment: Why this was closed as off topic... Are we not able to ask for such type of solutions?

Comment: It's borderline, but I would suggest posting this on ServerFault.com.